# set web hook for my telegram bot python script without flask

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram

I have a telegram bot python script, i use telepot package in my bot. so i want  to set web hook for it.part of my script is this:

```
import telepot
bot = telepot.Bot(token)
def handle(msg):
    print(msg)
```

I googled and i found out that i have to use flask and webhookorder() in this form:

```
from telepot.loop import OrderedWebhook

def handle(msg):
   # ......

bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
webhook = OrderedWebhook(bot, handle)
webhook.run_as_thread()
```

and i have to add this code:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook_path', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pass_update():
webhook.feed(request.data)
return 'OK'
```

but my server doesnt support flask.
is there another way to set webhook for my bot without flask.
or is there free host to support python and flask frameworker?

Comment: You can try setting a webhook between your bot and your script by calling `https://api.telegram.org/bot<yourBottoken>?url=<urlToYourScript>`.

Comment: yes,when i write a simple script i can set webhook between bot and my script but because i defined a function (the function name is handle(msg) in above) and my function has a parameter, when i call my function my script give error.